# Cell Image TableViewController Reposition

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I have two custom viewcontrollers which have UIImage and TableView. On the top of each viewcontroller I have the compnay logo and the content is in the tableView.

Even though these two viewcontrollers are created in the same way but, second figure tableview content (first row) touches the logo (image). This case does not exist in the second viewcontroller.

I could not able to figure out.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check `contentInsets` property of eech tableView. Also you might want to check type of the navigationBar in each view controller - `opaque` vs `translucent`.